# Data read from kafka into spark disappears after registration as a table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Consider data written from a `dataframe` to `kafka` and then read from `kafka` back out to a new `dataframe`:

```
// Write from df to kafka
val wdf  = airj.write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("topic", "air2008")
  .save
```

Now read the data back

```
// Read from kafka into spark df
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val flights = (spark.read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "air2008")
  .load())
```

How many records?

```
scala> flights.count
res36: Long = 5824436
```

Let's register this as a table:

```
flights.createOrReplaceTempView("flights_raw")
```

Let's ask that a *different way*: *how many records .. ??!*

```
spark.sql("select count(1) from flights_raw").show
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|0       |
+--------+
```

Let's ask the question the first way again:

```
scala> flights.count
res40: Long = 0
```

*What happened here ?*

Comment: `createOrReplaceTempView` returns `Unit` .. (that suggestion does not compile)

Comment: My bad! After creating the view `flights.createOrReplaceTempView("flights_raw")`
 try `spark.table("flights_raw").cache` and then `spark.table("flights_raw").count`

Comment: I created an answer along those lines. Feel free to basically copy and paste and put under your name and I can award.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createOrReplaceTempView` is lazily evaluated meaning that it does not persist to memory. To do so, you'd have to `cache` the data.

```
flights.cache
flights.createOrReplaceTempView("flights_raw")
```

or

```
flights.createOrReplaceTempView("flights_raw")
spark.table("flights_raw")
spark.table("flights_raw").cache
spark.table("flights_raw").count
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It is not so simple to just say the reason for the issue being that _createOrReplaceTempView_ is lazily evaluated. That should not cause the "now you see it now you don't" behavior.   There is a bug in there.. But i'm awarding since your comment made me try the _cache_ again (I had tried _persist_ and that did not solve the problem for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment from @GiorgosMyrianthous I put a `_cache_` in. It only helps if done *before* the `createOrReplaceTempView`: as follows

Does *not* work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val flights = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "air2008")
  .load()
flights.createOrReplaceTempView("flights_raw").cache
```

*works* :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val flights = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "air2008")
  .load()
flights.cache
flights.createOrReplaceTempView("flights_raw")
```

Now it works

```
scala> flights.count
res47: Long = 5824436
```